# WCF message response arriving after timeout expires

Tags: wcf, named-pipes

We have two applications (client and server) on the same machine that communicate via a WCF service using named pipes.

The issue that we're seeing is that occasionally a request from the client to the server will time out. WCF tracing is enabled on both ends, and on the server side we see the request being processed and responded to immediately as expected. However on the client side we don't see the response and the request times out after 1 minute.

What's suspicious is that almost immediately after the timeout, the client-side WCF trace shows the server's response arriving, almost as if it had been stuck somewhere and the timeout exception caused it to come un-stuck.

Attached are some screenshots from the client trace of the activity that relates to a particular message. Notice that the message gets sent out at 13:26:31.38, it times out at 13:27:31.80, and then the response gets received at 13:27:31.215.

Has anyone ever seen this behavior with WCF named pipes, where messages responses randomly seem to get stuck?

[image: Message gets sent out from client]

[image: WCF times out waiting for response]

[image: Response is received suspiciously close to after WCF times out]

Comment: Have you tried to increase the timeout value? 
<netNamedPipeBinding>
        <binding name="mybinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
 receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </netNamedPipeBinding>

Comment: Here is an official document. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/netnamedpipebinding

Comment: I have not tried to increase the timeout. I can try it, but I'm VERY skeptical that it would resolve the issue. This timeout has happened before on several occasions, and each time the trace shows the response from the server as coming in just 1 second after the timeout. That seems way too coincidental. I just don't believe that in the many times we've seen this that the response always just happens to arrive in exactly 61 seconds. A more plausible explanation is that something in WCF gets stuck until after the timeout expires, at which point it gets unstuck and the response gets processed.

Comment: Of note is that the WCF client calls are being run on the UI thread. Could this possibly be causing a deadlock or something until the timeout expires? It's not consistent or reproducible, but then again timing issues very rarely are.